# Unable to sign In with google account using Firebase authentication

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-authentication

This is the code., what the issue I am facing was "After clicking on 'Sign In With Google' button, it displays me the available list of Gmail Accounts but after selecting one of the account it doesn't navigates me to the main activity.

In Firebase, I have enabled "Google Sign In" and also added "SHA -1" and "SHA-256" keys as a fingerprint to my project.

In logs, I notice "activityResume Trigger : not Whitelisted" and also in the build.gradle(:app) I have "minifyEnabled: false" as shown below

buildTypes {
release {
minifyEnabled false
proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
}

So, could you please help me out in figuring what is the issue. Thanks in Advance.

```
package com.turbotechnologies.quizgame

import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.Intent
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.View
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultCallback
import androidx.activity.result.ActivityResultLauncher
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.Auth
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignIn
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInAccount
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInClient
import com.google.android.gms.auth.api.signin.GoogleSignInOptions
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.ApiException
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthCredential
import com.google.firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider
import com.turbotechnologies.quizgame.R.drawable
import com.turbotechnologies.quizgame.databinding.ActivityLoginBinding

class LoginActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    lateinit var loginBinding: ActivityLoginBinding
    private val auth: FirebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance()

    // Creating an object from google sign in client class
    lateinit var googleSignInClient: GoogleSignInClient

    lateinit var activityResultLauncher: ActivityResultLauncher<Intent>

    @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        loginBinding = ActivityLoginBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        val view = loginBinding.root
        setContentView(view)

       val textForGoogleSignInButton = loginBinding.buttonGoogleSignIn.getChildAt(0) as TextView
        // Changing the text of the google signIn button
        textForGoogleSignInButton.text = "Continue with Google"
        textForGoogleSignInButton.setTextColor(Color.BLACK)
        textForGoogleSignInButton.textSize = 18F
       textForGoogleSignInButton.setBackgroundResource(drawable.button_shape)

        // register the activity
        registeringActivityForGoogleSignIn()

        loginBinding.buttonGoogleSignIn.setOnClickListener {
            loginBinding.progressBar4.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            signInGoogle()
        }
        
    }

     private fun signInGoogle() {
         val gso = GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
            .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
            .requestEmail().build()
        googleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(ths,gso)
        signIn()
    }

    private fun signIn() {
        val signInIntent  = googleSignInClient.signInIntent
        activityResultLauncher.launch(signInIntent)
    }

    private fun registeringActivityForGoogleSignIn() {
        activityResultLauncher =
            registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult(),
                ActivityResultCallback { result ->
                    val resultCode = result.resultCode
                    val data = result.data

                    if (resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                        val task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount> =
                            GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data)
                            firebaseSignInWithGoogle(task)
                    }
                })
    }

    private fun firebaseSignInWithGoogle(task: Task<GoogleSignInAccount>) {
        try {
            val account: GoogleSignInAccount = task.getResult(ApiException::class.java)
            Toast.makeText(
                applicationContext,
                "Successfully logged in with Gmail account",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            // Opening the main activity
            val intent = Intent(this@LoginActivity, MainActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(intent)
            // Closing the login page as we opened main activity using the intent
            finish()
            firebaseGoogleAccount(account)
        } catch (e: ApiException) {
            Toast.makeText(applicationContext, e.localizedMessage, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
        }
    }

    private fun firebaseGoogleAccount(account: GoogleSignInAccount) {
        // creating an object from the auth credential class
        val authCredential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(
            // Parameter 1 -> account.idToken -> It is unique for each device and can know which device is logged in.
            account.idToken, null
        )
        auth.signInWithCredential(authCredential).addOnCompleteListener { task ->
            if (task.isSuccessful) {
                // Retrieve the user data, if login is done
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,"Logged In",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                // Creating an user object from the firebase user class
                //val user =
                  //  auth.currentUser // Hence, logged in user is assigned to the user object i.e., When the user logs in, it gives us the opportunity to access this data in there google account.
                // user?.email
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(applicationContext,task.exception?.localizedMessage,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }
}
```

After selecting one of google gmail account, I need to navigated to the Main Activity as I used "Intent" for this in the code.

Comment: I cannot spot the issue at first glance. Is any of the Toast messages displayed? Besides that, because you're using Kotlin, I think that this [resource](https://medium.com/firebase-developers/how-to-authenticate-to-firebase-using-google-one-tap-in-jetpack-compose-60b30e621d0d) will help. Here is the corresponding [repo](https://github.com/alexmamo/FirebaseSignInWithGoogle).

Comment: which version SHA you have added to firebase  DEBUG/RELEASE? Do you checking in same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked your codes, there are no mistakes. I even created a new project and just used your codes and Google login was successful. So I think the problem is caused by a different reason. First, make sure you add the SHA-1 key to your Firebase project. If not, add it and re-download the new google-services.json file and add it to your project. Then, in the Firebase console, don't forget to choose Google from the Sign-in method and define a support mail address here. Finally, be sure to add the Firebase auth and gms play services auth libraries to the dependencies section. If you are sure that you have done all these and you are still having problems, create a new Android project and a new Firebase project and continue through these projects.